# Relativistic Cellular Automata

Tags: cellular-automata, special-relativity, mp.mathematical-physics, nks

Cellular automata provide interesting models of physics: Google Scholar gives more than 25,000 results when searching for ["cellular automata" physics](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22cellular+automata%22+physics&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=2001&as_sdtp=on).

Google Scholar still gives more than 2,000 results when searching for ["quantum cellular automata"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22quantum+cellular+automata%22&btnG=Search&as_sdt=2000&as_ylo=&as_vis=0).

But it gives only [1](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=sab-9fGPCEcC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=%22relativistic+cellular+automata%22&ots=rG9eoNgPYh&sig=ZNQpI-0B-0S2358zX9To-h4NtdI#v=onepage&q=%22relativistic%20cellular%20automata%22&f=false) (one!) result when searching for ["relativistic cellular automata"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22relativistic+cellular+automata%22&btnG=Search&as_sdt=2000&as_ylo=&as_vis=0), i.e. cellular automata with a (discrete) Minkoswki space-time instead of an Euclidean one.

> How can this be understood?
>
> Why does the concept of QCA seem more
> promising than that of RCA?
>
> Are there conceptual or technical barriers for a thorough treatment of RCA?

Comment: Hans, when A New Kind of Science came out, the most compelling reason I had heard of why CA couldn't reflect physics was because no one had ever successfully modeled Minkoswki space-time with them. Sorry, this isn't a real answer because I can provide neither a citation nor a technical explanation. I can just verify that there is a difficulty here.

Comment: As for "A New Kind of Science" and plausibility of modelling Minkowski spacetime with cellular automata, also check out: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0206089 (book review by Scott Aaronson)

Comment: So has this question then *doubled* the number of google hits to "relativistic cellular automata"?  :)

Comment: No, since MO is not indexed by Google Scholar. (Maybe it should be?)

Comment: @Hans: Good point.  Perhaps it should.  Who decides that?  Google?


Comment: I'm quite sure that it's Google's decision. Whose else?

Comment: In 2018 there are five hits for relativistic cellular automata

Answer (score 14):

One of the reasons that it may be difficult to model Minkowski space based on cellular automata is that [there are no "non-trivial" finite sub-groups of $O(3,1)$](http://jmp.aip.org/resource/1/jmapaq/v21/i2/p234_s1), where non-trivial means that it doesn't just reduce to just a finite sub group of $O(3)$ via conjugation. So while cellular automata can be manifestly be homogeneous and isotropic (so admits a discrete $O(3)$ symmetry), it becomes conceptually difficult to imagine some cellular automata capturing Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: Why Galilean?  Shouldn't the result be that any finite subgroup of $O(3,1)$ is conjugate to $O(3) \times O(1)$?  If so, then you don't need any Galilean transformations (e.g., translations or Galilean boosts): up to conjugation your subgroup is generated by reflections and time reversal.  Strictly speaking these are Galilean, to be sure, but saying Galilean is slightly misleading.

Comment: A second comment is that this group-theoretical fact might be a red herring.  There are certainly discrete approaches (albeit not based on cellular automata, AFAIK) to try to capture lorentzian geometry.  One particularly interesting one is that of causal sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_sets), for example.

Comment: Added to the first of my comments: I guess I forgot to say that the Galilean group is not a subgroup of $O(3,1)$, which is why I thought that it was a little misleading to say "Galilean".

Comment: @Jose: sorry about the O(3) bit. Now fixed. I tried to use Galilean to emphasize that it breaks Lorentz symmetry, a choice that obviously back-fired in this case. I omitted the O(1) factor since, well, it is either time reversing or not. That factor is not particularly interesting. I know about Causal set theory, but notice that unlike cellular automata, the points in causal set theory are not put all on equal footing. (The total graph needs to be embeddable into a Lorentzian manifold, but nodes need not be "isomorphic".) One of the assumptions of cellular automata is that the structures

Comment: ... involved can be captured locally (at least all the versions I have seen), which suggests to me that the grid must have some sort of homogeneity assumption. Which is why I think the group argument is compelling for why there isn't a bona fide discrete and homogeneous model of Minkowski space, and hence also a lack of relativistic CA. 

Comment: On the other hand, if you have a notion of cellular automata which is not necessarily isotropic nor homogeneous, obviously a group theoretic argument will not apply. This is sort of the content of the last sentence in my posted answer. 

Comment: @Willie: many thanks for the comments.  I understand your answer better now.  I know next to nothing about cellular automata, whence I had thought your answer had to do with the discreteness.

Comment: @Willie: You say that "cellular automata can be manifestly homogeneous and isotropic". Given the handwaving definitions "isotropic = having the same property in all directions" and "homogeneous = having the same property in one region as in every other region" (see e.g. http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=1355248&postcount=3) I understand the homogenity part, but not the isotropy part: when a cellular automaton is based on a grid, there are distinguished directions, aren't there?

Comment: @Hans Stricker: what I had in mind is a totalistic CA like Life, where the central state depends only on the number of nearest neighbors that are alive. More precisely, you can imagine a CA being a map locally from the $3^n$ box of 0,1s to the value of the next center. An isotropy condition will require invariance under suitable rotations of this $3^n$ box. In other words, isotropy is not so much about invariance under "ambient directions", but about the directions allowed in the system. 

Comment: On the other hand, one should note again, that if you consider most general CAs like Wolfram did in NKS, then no, the isotropy condition can be broken. But You don't need to have a totalistic CA to get isotropy: total number of alive cells is only one algebraic invariant. There are other algebraic invariants. In two dimensions, for example, you can divide the 3 by 3 grid into three classes: 4 corner values, 4 edge values, and the center. Take two symmetric polynomials in 4 variables and and one polynomial of one variable. Applying the symmetric polynomial to the each class and sum, you get an 

Comment: ... invariant (this doesn't exhaust all rotation invariant rules, by the way). For any such notion of istropy, my objection will stand. Of course, this is not a theorem that says it is impossible to model Minkowski space dynamics in this way, it is just, from my point a view, an indication that something a lot more complicated needs to be in play if you want to consider relativity in a CA framework. A key point is that whereas "quantum" is a condition on the "laws of physics/dynamics", "relativistic" really is a condition on "geometry of space-time".

Answer (score 11):

What Willie's answer shows is that, for some non-trivial Lorentz-translatable cellular automaton, every cell would need an infinite number of neighbors. This cellular automaton couldn't work if any cell had an infinite number of live neighbors. As was pointed out in the comments (2018), it could work if there were only a finite number of live neighbors of any cell. One would need to impose constraints on which kinds of configurations are allowed to ensure this, though.

There's a way of getting around this, however. You could make each cell correspond to a point in space-time and also a boost (a boost is essentially a velocity in the Lorentz group). Then, cells would interact with cells both close to them in space-time and also close in boost. I don't know whether anybody has considered cellular automata like this.

In order for this to have a correspondence to realistic quantum field theories, it would have to be the case that when two particles interact at a high boost, the interaction strength goes to 0 as the boost goes to infinity. I don't know whether this is true, although the thought experiment of considering particles falling into a black hole through a sea of Hawking radiation makes it seem like it might be.

Comment: For those (like me) to whom "boost" is a new term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation helps.

Comment: Joseph: Sorry. I guess I could have used "velocity," but that sounds wrong to ears that have been listening to too many physicists. 

Comment: @PeterShor Why is it contradictory for a cell to have an infinite number of neighbours? It's certainly possible to define an automaton where each cell $(x, t)$ depends on (say) the set of points $(y, s)$ satisfying $(t - s)^2 = 2(y - x)^2 + 1$ and $s < t$ (the latter 'orthochronous' condition making everything into a DAG as required a la causality).

Comment: @Adam: In a non-trivial Lorentz-translatable cellular automaton, each cell would have to depend on an infinite number of other cells.

Comment: @PeterShor I understand entirely, but I don't see why that's contradictory. Having an infinite neighbourhood $N$ doesn't prevent one from defining a function $f : S^N \rightarrow S$ (where $S$ is the state space); indeed, there are uncountably many from which to choose.

Comment: Yes, but the function has to be invariant in some sense under Lorentz shifts. Thus, each point in $N$ has to have an equal weight on the function value.

Comment: Agreed! Any permutation-invariant function would trivially satisfy that requirement (such as "a cell if live if and only if there are exactly three live neighbours*").

* perhaps 'precursor' would be more appropriate than 'neighbour' since the latter suggests a symmetric relation.

Comment: So you're right; there are Lorentz-invariant evolution functions if each cell only has a finite number of live neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this very same question at physics.stackexchange, too (do the policies of MO have anything against this?), and got an interesting hint, which I leave to your attention:

[Cellular automata methods in mathematical physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/887/relativistic-cellular-automata/896#896)

Comment: Cross-site duplicates are OK if they make sense on both. Manually linking questions between them is also a good practice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/are-similar-questions-allowed-on-two-sites